# Can't initialize a std::array of std::array

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdarray

In this piece of code the initialisation of the `Foo` does not compile, I get the error `error: too many initializers for 'std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>`.

On the other hand the initialisations of `FooOK`, `FooOK1D` and  `Bar` compile fine.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> Foo
{
  {1,2,3},   // does not compile: error: too many initializers for 'std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>'
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,9}
};

std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> FooOK
{
    1,2,3    // compiles fine
};


std::array<int, 3> FooOK1D
{
    1,2,3    // compiles fine
};

std::vector<std::vector<int>> Bar
{
  {1,2,3},   // compiles fine
  {4,5,6},
  {7,8,9}
};
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: `std::array` is a type with `T[N]` inside, so aggregate initialization (might) need extra `{}` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PEs1r34P1)